# unit test delayed block of Android app with Robolectric

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I want to test execution of a block scheduled with `View#postDelayed(Runnable, delay)`. So before asserting I call `Robolectric.runUiThreadTasksIncludingDelayedTasks()`. But there the test code gets stuck, i.e. does not return.

I am sure that that delayed block is called if I run the app directly.

Is this a bug of the runUiThreadTasksIncludingDelayedTasks() or are there any other preconditions to use it?

Thx,
Mick

Comment: Did you fix your issue? Did you try with "runBackgroundTasks"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works with latest release version of Robolectric.

Answer (score 1):

With Robolectric 3.8 you can use:

```
Robolectric.flushForegroundThreadScheduler()
```

This executes all runnables that have been enqueued on the foreground scheduler.